# Use css Grid to divide unknow number of items into two columns, but list in column order

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a number of items I wish to divide into two even columns.

I have an example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2o2cVvgSBrS3gIc7?preview)

So I have a number of items..

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

and this gives me

[image]

But what I want is for the items to "flow" down the columns, ie they will be in the order

```
 1        4
 2        5
 3        6
```

I thought the property `grid-auto-flow` would do this, but I can't get it to do what I am after

Is there an easy way I can do this (preferably with css grid)?

Comment: Can you not change your html structure to get the desired output? Easiest way would be to just re-order the grid items.

Comment: Another way by just making a small change in your html structure: [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/NNkg4LQFC0xYVlQx). If you don't want to change the html, then you could look at `grid-area` property or manually assigning column/row to grid items

Comment: For the html layout the plunk was just to demonstrate. In the actual app, the number of items will be unknown, and stamped out via an iterator (eg Angular `*ngFor`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't always have to be the latest layout technique; sometimes there already is an older one that was specifically created to get the job at hand done.

That being said, consider using [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns), which does what you want, out of the box:

```css
#parent {
  columns: 2;
}

.item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

**Important Side Note:** As @Yousaf has pointed out, this can lead to a single item being spread to two columns, because the browsers tries to make sure both columns are about the same height. To avoid that, simply use

```
break-inside: avoid;
```

for the column items.

Comment: This will probably produce weird layout if the number of items are odd.

Comment: @Yousaf Good point. It's only about the number of items being odd if all items have the same height. In that case the middle item is spread to both columns.

Comment: @Yousaf `.item { break-inside: avoid; }` avoids that problem.

Comment: Thankyou, that does achieve what I was after. Just for education would be interested if grid could do this, but I can just use the above.